# Does Restoring a Time Machine Backup Repair the OS?

Tags: macos, time-machine, high-sierra, recovery-hd

Ok I understand I can reinstall Mac OS from the Command + R Menu and the OS is reinstalled without touching (we hope) my files unless I erase the disk first.
However, what if I just choose to restore a Time Machine Backup? 
Is any disk repair or OS repair performed or is it just a clone of the last backup? 
Any corruption in the Time Machine Backup would  not be repaired but rather put back on its corrupt state?
Is the recommended Troubleshooting Procedure to always reinstall MacOS and then restore your TimeMachine Backup?

Comment: can you describe your problem a little bit further? What data is corrupt?

Comment: The Mac would not boot after installing software. I wanted to get in to remove the software and Safe Mode would not work. My question is more about what is the difference between reinstall OS and restore from TimeMachine and whether and repairs are done to the OS during TineMachine restore or do I reinstall the OS separately?